# Codeigniter - Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Tags: codeigniter

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/aphotel/public_html/application/config/config.php:1)

Filename: libraries/Session.php

Line Number: 366
```

#

Weird part of it, there is no session.php file in libraries folder

Comment: As mentioned, I should have read some of the other posts here, I just found the solution this by the follwing: 


place this ob_start(); on first line of index.php under your application directory like this :

'
<?php
ob_start();
/*
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
 * APPLICATION ENVIRONMENT
 *---------------------------------------------------------------
'

Comment: possible duplicate of [Headers already sent by PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/headers-already-sent-by-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974891/codeigniter-message-cannot-modify-header-information-headers-already-sent-by check this

Answer (score 8):

I had this problem before and it was caused by output_buffering was Off.

Edit your php.ini and search for output_buffering and make it looks like this

```
output_buffering = On
```

Comment: Thanks! Works for me.

Answer (score 8):

In PHP
   Use " ob_start(); " at  first line
   and in CI controller constructor
   at first line
    " ob_start(); " //output buffer

Answer (score 4):

Remove print_r(); in controller, model or session. There are problem or warning when website upload in host server not warning in localhost

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you do not have any white space characters before the opening php tag  in your controller class.

Answer (score 4):

There seems to be whitespace before the php open tag

Answer (score 4):

There is space before the `<?php` tag in the below file. I have seen this issue multiple times.

```
(output started at /home/aphotel/public_html/application/config/config.php:1)
```

Answer (score 3):

I changed encoding to 'UTF-8 without BOM' for all php files in model, controller and helper folders and that helped.

Answer (score 2):

Just load session library first.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'encrypt', 'database',...
```