# Codeigniter: Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have created a dynamic menu CMS website. I developed in a Windows system. When i run my project in windows operating system, My project runs without any error. But now uploaded it into Linux Operating system server i am getting warning & error like:

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

    Severity: Warning

    Message: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/ansofcm8/public_html/apps/resources/math/application/core/MY_Controller.php:1)

    Filename: libraries/Session.php

    Line Number: 675
```

What could be the reason. Please help me.

Comment: @JohnConde Thank you . I will delete this question after solving this issue

Comment: show us the Session.php file at line 675

Comment: lol, dont delete it, give at least one vote to Jonh Conde who helped you!

Comment: @Tomás I given him vote. Thank you

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There seems to be whitespace before the php open tag `<?php` in MY_Controller.php.

Check all PHP files and remove the whitespace before the `<?php` tag. If there is a space or new line, the body of the http request is started, and you can't add new headers to the http request.

Comment: Yep, is a whitespace. 
@Burls Willis check `headers already sent by (output started at MY_Controller.php:1)`. It's pointing to line 1, and the only thing that is sending something to the frontend on the first lines in a php file are whitespaces.

Comment: @phpNoOb  So what should i do in that line? Shall i give more space or shall give no space before php opne tag `<?php`

Comment: @BurlsWillis no space, remove al. Updated my original answer with an explanation.

Comment: @BurlsWillis Also don't for get to check models/mainmenumodel.php and remove the wihtespace/newline there.

Comment: yes Its a Whitespace error before <?php tag...

Comment: For my issue, I had a php cron task that hit that controller every 5 minutes to run a function. That php cron file caused the session headers already sent issue. I had to move my session_start in that controller into a function that was NOT called by the cron php task. That fixed it.

Comment: @Robot70 Same issue on me, but I don't have `session_start()` on my controller, it is in `system/libraries/Session/Session.php`, and what error I get is 
`ERROR - 2020-03-02 15:24:02 --> Severity: Warning --> ini_set(): Headers already sent. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`
and more ... 
Do you have any solution?

Comment: highjump, i would read Jesse's comment on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814895/message-ini-set-a-session-is-active-you-cannot-change-the-session-modules