# Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, apache2

I created a login page with codeigniter,but i get the php message.

`Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

how to fix this?

**view (login.php)**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Admin Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/normalize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/admin-style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <?php echo form_open('Verify_login', ['id'=>'loginForm', 'name'=>'loginForm', 'method'=>'post']) ?>
    <div class="login">
        <div class="log-box">
            <h3>Login</h3>
            <div >
                  <input id="username" name="username" placeholder="User Name" value="" type="text" >
                <?php echo form_error('username'); ?>
                <input id="Password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required type="password">
                <?php echo form_error('password'); ?>
                <div class="remember-me">
                    <input id="checkBox" type="checkbox">
                    <label for="checkBox">Remember Me</label>
                </div>
                <button class="login-button" name="loginButton">Login</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**controller (Verify_login.php)**

```
<?php 
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access aloowed');

class Verify_login extends CI_Controller
{

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('User');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('security');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->library('session');
}

public function index()
{
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|callback_check_database');
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        // if validation failed load the view 
        $this->load->view('admin/login');
    }

    else{
        $this->check_database($username , $password);
        redirect('dashboard', 'refresh');
    }
}

public function check_database($password)
{
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query tha database
    $result = $this->User->login($username, $password);

    if ($result) {
        $sess_array = [];
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $sess_array = 
                [
                    'id'=>$row->id,
                    'username'=>$row->name
                ];
            $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
        }
        return TRUE;
    }
    else{

        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database','invalid username and password');
    }
  }
 }
?>
```

**controller(Admin.php)**

```
session_start(); //need to call PHP's session object to access it though it
class Admin extends CI_Controller
{

public $data;
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->helper('security');

    //load user model
    $this->load->model('User');

}
public function index()
{
    // $this->load->view('admin/index');
    if ($this->session->userdata('logged_in')) {

        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
        $data['username'] = $session_data['name'];
        $this->load->view('admin/dashboard', $data);
    }
    else{

        //if no session redirect to login page 
        redirect('admin', 'refresh');
        // redirect('login');
    }
}

public function logout()
{
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();
    redirect('home', 'refresh');
}
```

**model (User.php)**

```
<?php
```

/**
    *user login claass which extends MY_Model 
    *
    */

```
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('no direct script allowed');

class User extends CI_Model
{
    protected $table = 'users';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function login($username ,$password)
    {
        var_dump($username);
        var_dump($password);
        $this->db->select(['id', 'name', 'password']);
        $this->db->from($this->table);
        // $this->db->where('name', $username);
        // $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $this->db->limit(1);

        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() == 1) {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else{

            return false;
        }
    }
   }    
   ?>
```

Comment: Please provide some code or provide things you have tried. This message means you are trying to change the session modules settings after a session_start

Comment: check phpinfo() to see if your config has session.auto_start set on?

Comment: sure session.auto_start off.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need this line in **admin.php**

```php
session_start(); //need to call PHP's session object to access it though it
```

When you load the session library, its constructor does this for you.

Comment: The user probably followed some sample which is based on pre CI3 version. I also got this error while upgrading my CI2 project to CI3

Comment: @BiLaL I don't think it is best practice to keep an line before a class. If you need to you can use **constructors** in class.

Comment: Yes, i totally agree with you its not a best practice. php is not my domain, I also got such examples and it worked in CI2. In .NET such statements are not even entertained

Comment: And why CI 3 is losing the session after call a new method?

Answer (score 11):

The message means that you have started a session with `session_start()` in which further down in the code you are using `ini_set()` to manipulate the session module. If you are manipulating the session module, it should be done before a session is started and active.

Comment: Or in other words: `Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time`

Answer (score 5):

This is really working for me

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {

// server should keep session data for AT LEAST 24 hour
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);

// each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 24 hour
session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24);
session_start();
}
```

so you do start your session after calling ini_set and session_set_cookie_params etc

Answer (score 3):

**Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time**

I had same error message sometime ago , By default Code-igniter will write to file (*C:\xampp\tmp*) in my case. But I want it to write to database instead.

In your autoloader you might have had something like this:

```
//:::::$autoload['libraries'] = array();
//'session', this mean start session ini_set()
$autoload['libraries'] = array('session', 'database');
```

By default setting in the config/config.php  session configurartion look like this:

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = NULL;
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

The [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#using-the-session-class) stated that to use database instead of file you should first create a table in application database.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ci_sessions` (
        `id` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        `ip_address` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        `timestamp` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        `data` blob NOT NULL,
        KEY `ci_sessions_timestamp` (`timestamp`)
);
```

Go back to the *config/config.php* and change `$config['sess_driver'] = 'files';` to `$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';`

Like so I thought everything should be fine but I got the error **Message: ini_set(): A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time**

My Solution was to first run the `session_destroy();`

Then change session name and table name

My config look like this :

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'newname_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 72000;
$config['sess_save_path'] ='newname_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

**Save everything and after refresh the page all cleared, no error message showing**

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
   // server should keep session data for AT LEAST 24 hour
   ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60 * 60 * 24);

   session_start();

   // each client should remember their session id for EXACTLY 24 hour
   session_set_cookie_params(60 * 60 * 24);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its worth noting that in CI4 you can get this error message if you are changing databases within your models. If your session cannot update, it will call baseHandler `fail()` which errors an output.

The solution is to set your App.php in Config to `public $sessionSavePath = 'db.table';` which should fix it.

Answer (score -1):

You can handle this issue by only running the command when it's needed like this:

```php
if (!isset($_SESSION)
    && !headers_sent()
) {
    session_start();
}
```

Answer (score -5):

1. Go to file \system\libraries\Session\Session.
2. Uncomment session_start() at line 143 and you are done.

Comment: kindly consider explaining your answer in greater detail so that OP can understand

Comment: I'd recommend against this because you're modifying system files which can be whipped out if the code base is updated. Best practice would be to make changes to  the application files (such as admin.php) as mentioned in an earlier answer.